# NoMethodError: undefined method `ensure_reset_password_token!' devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords, rubygems, reset

I was trying to use a call like:

`User.first.ensure_reset_password_token!`

and it gives me an error:

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `ensure_reset_password_token!' ``

In my model I have:

`devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable`

I set up in routes:

`devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/passwords" }`

So why can't I use this method if I can use all methods that aren't protected from here http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of devise gem are you using? Looks like that method is removed in devise-2.1.3

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb) version of the recoverable.rb

Comment: Yes - that was the problem. Thanks :) When I was viewing the code on the github repo for the devise gem it was showing me the master branch where <code> ensure_reset_password_token!</code> still exists https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L52